# Does the feat Unnatural Mantle keep this servitor in the fight?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, saving-throw, powers, hit-points

The cleric prayer **Servitude in Death** has as its effect

> The first time the target dies before the end of the encounter, it rises at the start of its next turn as an undead creature **allied with you and your allies**. Until it dies again, the creature is dominated by you. It has 1 hit point…. (*Heroes of Shadow* 83 and emphasis mine)

The feat **Unnatural Mantle** says

> While you have at least 1 power point, **allies** within the area of your Ardent Mantle remain conscious when dropped to 0 or fewer hit points until they roll their first death saving throw. (*Dragon* #389 31 and emphasis mine)

Does the Unnatural Mantle feat interact with undead creature that rises as the result of the Servitude in Death prayer when that servitor is reduced to 0 hp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Death saves are PC-only.

So unless this is a ridiculous friendly fire incident, this doesn't really apply:

> Monsters and characters controlled by the Dungeon Master usually die when their hit points drop to 0, unless an adventurer chooses to knock them unconscious.
>
> *Rules Compendium* p.261, "Dying and Death"

Technically the creature is still being controlled by the Dungeon Master, you're just dominating it. So when it drops to 0 hit points, it dies immediately.